# subversion not able to list or export

Tags: svn, list, export

I need to export some project from a repo at my work, im using a different machine that I have not usually use, and have discovered that using the command line im having some troubles checking out and listing the repo,

so for testing purposes I use:

> $ svn export http://linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/trunk/BOOK

and get this response

> svn: OPTIONS of 'http://linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/trunk/BOOK': 200 OK (http://linuxfromscratch.org)

same response if i just use

> $ svn list http://linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/trunk/BOOK

so...

- what is the

> 200 OK

- also, for my real export, i need to provide username and password, so how would the export command look like?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL doesn't appear to exist:

```
$ curl -I http://linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/trunk/BOOK
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

This, however, does work:

```
svn export svn://svn.linuxfromscratch.org/BLFS/trunk
```

Your subversion client should prompt you for a username and password when you attempt the export.